# Grid Lines Are too Wide in Density Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have implemented a density plot in R using ggplot2 (updated version):

```
library(ggplot2)

densityplot <- function(values, pointsInTime, title) {
    df <- data.frame(x = 1:length(pointsInTime), y = values)
    p <-
        ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        geom_area(alpha = 0.5, fill = '#42a5ed') +
        geom_line(color = '#42a5ed') +
        geom_point(
            color = '#42a5ed',
            fill = 'white',
            shape = 21,
            size = 3
        ) +
        scale_x_continuous(labels = pointsInTime, breaks = 1:length(df$x)) +
        theme(
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = '#dddddd'),
            panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(10, 0, 0, 0)),
            axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(0, 10, 0, 0)),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 18),
            axis.title = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks = element_blank()
        ) +
        coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, xlim=min(df$x):max(df$x), ylim=0:max(df$y)+1) +
        labs(title = title)
    p
}
densityplot(sample(10:25, size = s),
            format(ISOdate(2017, 1:12, 1), "%b"),
            "Number of Fatal Accidents")
```

[image]

**Update**: Now the 'Dec' label on the bottom right is cut off. Is there a way to add margin or spacing?

**Initial Problem**: The horizontal grid lines in the background are too wide. I want them to just begin where the 'Jan' tick resp. to end where the 'Dec' tick would be; just covering the actual plot area, not the whole panel. However, I want to have the space around the panel to stay the same, i.e. the axis labels should not move towards the data.

Comment: You'll need to turn off axis expansion, either with `+ coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` or `+ scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))`.

Comment: @Axeman: That works. However, I'd rather have some space around the panel. `panel.spacing` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited your question and re-opened. You'll likely need to still turn off the expansion, but also deal with the spacing.

Comment: @Axeman Thank you, I didn't realize what making the lines narrower would do to the overall layout.

Comment: You can use `axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(0, 20, 0, 0))` to move the text further from the data. A dirty solution is `+ annotate('rect', xmin = -Inf, xmax = 1, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = 'white')`.

Comment: I now have a combination of margins and deactivated the expansion of the coordinates. This, unfortunately, cuts of 'Dec' at the very bottom right.

Comment: Perhaps turning off clipping might help, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41575505/4341440).