# Export large dataframe to a pdf file

Tags: r, pdf

I want to export my dataframe to a pdf file. Dataframe is pretty large, so it is causing problems while exporting. I used gridExtra package as specified here [writing data frame to pdf table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321127/writing-data-frame-to-pdf-table) but it did not work for my dataframe as it contains a lot of data.

Any ideas how it can be achieved?

Code:

```
library(gridExtra)
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

pdf(file = "df2.pdf")

grid.table(df)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Please provide code and example dataframe that "did not work".

Comment: Did you get any error ? Can you post it here.

Comment: @zx8754 I have updated the description to include code and data. It does not throw any error, but it just squeeze the dataframe partially on one page in the pdf rather than expanding it to the required number of pages.

Comment: @Indi plz see my above comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Baqir, you can try solution given on this link:
https://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2016/01/02/creating-pdf-documents-with-rrstudio/

It will be like this:

```
    library(grid)    
    library(gridExtra)  
    df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))    
    dim(df)  
    maxrow = 35   
    npages = ceiling(nrow(df)/maxrow)      
    pdf("test.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)  
    idx = seq(1, maxrow)  
    grid.table(df[idx,],rows = NULL)  
    for(i in 2:npages){
      grid.newpage();
      if(i*maxrow <= nrow(df)){
      idx = seq(1+((i-1)*maxrow), i * maxrow)
    }
    else{
      idx = seq(1+((i-1)*maxrow), nrow(df))
    }
    grid.table(df[idx, ],rows = NULL)
    }
    dev.off()
```

Hope this works!

Comment: @ShiwaniVeer how can I integrate a title and footnote that repeats across all the pages in my pdf? Your solution works well, but I need a title and footnote to go across all these pages.

Comment: @Pryore go to the link provided. There's a better example using sweave (essentially latex). So latex code should work. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers

Answer (score 0):

@Pryore, I found some part of the solution from the link:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644728/add-image-png-file-to-header-of-pdf-file-created-with-r)

Here is the code for header and footer.
Hope this works!

```
      makeHeader <- function(headerText= "your header", size= 1, color= grey(.5))
        {
          require(grid)
          pushViewport(viewport())
          grid.text(label= headerText,
                    x = unit(1,"npc") - unit(110, "mm"),
                    y = unit(270.8, "mm"),
                    gp=gpar(cex= size, col=color))
          popViewport()
        }

      makeFootnote <- function(footnoteText= "your footnote", 
                                  size= 1, color= grey(.5))
        {
          require(grid)
          pushViewport(viewport())
          grid.text(label= footnoteText ,
                    x = unit(1,"npc") - unit(27, "mm"),
                    y = unit(3, "mm"),
                    gp=gpar(cex= size, col=color))
          popViewport()
        }

     library(grid)    
     library(gridExtra)
        df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))    
        dim(df)  
        maxrow = 35   
        npages = ceiling(nrow(df)/maxrow)      
        pdf("trial.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)  
        idx = seq(1, maxrow)  
        grid.table(df[idx,],rows = NULL)  
        for(i in 1:npages){
          grid.newpage();
        makeFootnote()
        makeHeader()
          if(i*maxrow <= nrow(df)){
          idx = seq(1+((i-1)*maxrow), i * maxrow)
        }
        else{
          idx = seq(1+((i-1)*maxrow), nrow(df))
        }
        grid.table(df[idx, ],rows = NULL)
        }
        dev.off()
```